# fetch specific columns from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch specific columns from a table using phpmyadmin but it gives me sytanx error

my statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `node_revisions` WHERE `nid` =4,5,8,20;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean specific rows (not columns). You have to use in:

```
SELECT * FROM `node_revisions` WHERE `nid` in (4,5,8,20);
```

or `AND` concatinated where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM `node_revisions` WHERE `nid` =4 AND `nid` =5 AND `nid` =8 AND `nid` =20;
```

Comment: Fast as lightning hehe :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to write:

```
SELECT * FROM `node_revisions` WHERE `nid` in (4,5,8,20);
```

Does this help?